# Is this equation known?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

When I was trying to prove a relation from solid state physics, I reached this mathematical problem. In the equation

$$\sum_{i=1}^Nm_ix_i=n$$

$m_i$ and $n$ are known integers, $N=3$, and $x_i$ are unknown integers. Also we know that the greatest common factor of $\left\{m_i\right\}$ is 1. I don't need to find the solution; I must just show/state that the answer exists.

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to find ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the greatest common divisor of $m_1, \dots, m_N$ divides $n$, then this has a solution, by [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#For_three_or_more_integers).  If not, there is no solution, since the gcd will divide the left for any choice of $x_i$, but will never divide the right.

Comment: In this example, the greatest factor is 2 and it doesn't divide 13, but you still get a plane where the equation holds: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10x%2B14y%2B22z%3D13 I may be misunderstanding your answer

Comment: In your example, there are no _integer_ solutions, which OP was looking for.  Of course if you relax to non-integer solutions there are many more :) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer+solutions+10x%2B14y%2B22z%3D13

Comment: Ah right, didn't notice that :)

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the English language well enough: 1 divides any integer. Am I right?

Comment: Yes! If the greatest common divisor of the integers is 1, then your equation has a solution for any $n$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard result from *Arithmetic*:

The ideal $\;(x_1,\dots , x_N)\subset\mathbf Z$ generated by $x_1, \dots, x_n$, i.e. the set of linear combinations of $x_1,\dots, x_N$ with integer coefficients is the principal ideal generated by $\gcd(x_1,\dots,x_N)$.

Hence, if the generators are coprime, this ideal is $\mathbf Z$, generated by $1$, and any multiple of the g.c.d., i.e. any integer is attained.